# How to Add a new Column with Special Character Count in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

| Example Col | Example Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | words : words2 = |
| Cell 3 | examplewords:continued |

Hi! I am trying to create a third column where I can get the amount of colons and equal signs in the Example Col2. For example, the first row of the third added column would be 2, and the second row would be 1.

This is what I have tried so far, but I have had no luck. I am really new to PowerShell, so thanks for the help!

Comment: Change `-InputObject $_.$Data` to `-InputObject $_.'Example Col2'` - otherwise PowerShell won't know which column you're looking in :)

Comment: As aside, try to avoid using `$Matches` as your variable name. This is an automatic variable

Comment: Hmm, this gives me 0 for the count, any thoughts as to why?

Answer (score 1):

If your data comes from a csv file like this:

```
"Example Col","Example Col2"
"Cell 1","words : words2 ="
"Cell 3","examplewords:continued"
```

Then you could do

```
$data = Import-Csv -Path 'X:\Path\example.csv' | 
Select-Object *, @{Name = 'Example Col3'; Expression = {
    # (Select-String -InputObject $_.'Example Col2' -Pattern "[:=]" -AllMatches).Matches.Count}
    # a faster option:
    [regex]::Matches($_.'Example Col2', '[:=]').Groups.Count }
}

$data
```

If however you want to use `Add-Member` on the objects held in an array in memory, you could loop trhough like

```
$data | ForEach-Object {
    # $count = (Select-String -InputObject $_.'Example Col2' -Pattern "[:=]" -AllMatches).Matches.Count
    # a faster option:
    $count = [regex]::Matches($_.'Example Col2', '[:=]').Groups.Count
    $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Example Col3' -Value $count
}

$data
```

Result:

```
Example Col Example Col2           Example Col3
----------- ------------           ------------
Cell 1      words : words2 =                  2
Cell 3      examplewords:continued            1
```

Comment: Hi! I'm assuming the first method you shared is faster? When I use it, it prints out the correct result in the console, but does not when I export as a CSV. any ideas why? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Jasmine How are you exporting to CSV again? `$data |Export-Csv path\to\output.csv -NoTypeInformation` should do the trick...

Comment: @Jasmine Yes, the first should be faster, but it depends on what data we're using (an imported csv or an already present object array you wish to update). In both cases, `$data | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\Path\example_Update.csv' -NoTypeInformation` should export just fine including the new column

Comment: I am using an imported csv and saving later in the script (outside of the function that would be adding in the third column) by using the following code  $total = "$location" + '\' +"Final_Reports" + "\" + 'Compliance_Report-' + $date +'.csv'
    $Data | Export-CSV -Path $total

Comment: @Jasmine If you update the array inside a function, you need to addres it inside that function as `$script:data`, otherwise you are using a variable that only exists within the function and is lost outside. This is called [Scoping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes), Can you show your code in the question?

Comment: just added it! Thank you for the help. Any areas where you see improvement would be huge as I am SUPER new and need to learn how to be efficient with my logic

Comment: @Jasmine As said, you need to use scoping inside your function `dataManipulation`. Use `$script:guardiumData` or `$global:guardiumData` there instead of plain `$guardiumData`. Also, call the `main` function **before** you do the export

Comment: @Jasmine Your question was how to add a new, calculated column, not about the errors in your script that all have to do with scoping issues. I have had a close look at your script (thanks for posting that) and I feel you are over-complicating things by wanting to manipulate all kinds of variables inside functions (where scoping is needed) and on top of that try to have it all done inside a scriptblock.

Comment: @Jasmine My advise is to remove the scriptblock all together, remove some really unnecessary variables, update objects in the code itself instead of trying to do so in functions and have a close look at the order in which you write the commands in order to have some logic in there. Always try to keep code as simple as possible, so you don't get in trouble later when you need to make some adjustments. Inline comments also help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Can't say it'd be more efficient than Theo's solution above, but if you wanted an alternative to Select-String matching you could use replace with length property.

```
$data = $(
    [PSCustomObject]@{ 'Example Col' = 'Cell 1'; 'Example Col2' = 'words : words2 =' }
    [PSCustomObject]@{ 'Example Col' = 'Cell 3'; 'Example Col2' = 'examplewords:continued' }
)

$data | ForEach-Object {
    $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Example Col3' -Value ($_.'Example Col2' -replace '[^:=]').Length
}
```

Comment: Don't sell yourself short, I strongly suspect `-replace '[^...]'` will perform better than `Select-String` here :)